# Graph API post to wall limitation

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there any limitation to post to the Facebook wall using Graph API? Because after posting four messages using the Graph API, the fifth message cannot be posted. However, the sixth message can be posted. All the six posts are within a 10-minute timeframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no rate limit on the API officially, but Facebook can choose to limit your posts for any number of reasons.

Also, Facebook will not let you post the same message twice. Even if it came from a source other than your application. So, you can't post the same update that the user posted directly or came in via Twitter, if they have that set to sync.

If you are getting a specific error I will update my answer with more direct information.

Comment: I just succeeded posting a duplicate message from my app.